# Created file showing forbidden 403 error

Tags: php, file, http-status-code-403

I created a script and I selected datas from my database and created a file for each of the database output. As you can see below, `$home` is a variable assigned to my root folder:

```
<?php
$home = "http://localhost";
include $home.'/connect.php';

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tags");
$mysql = mysqli_num_rows($query);
while($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $tags[] = $sql['tag_names'];
}

foreach($tags as $tag){
$dir = $home."/forums/tags/".$tag;
$file_to_create = "index.php";
$file_content = "<?php include '".$home."/all_tags.php'; ?>";

    if(mkdir($dir)){
        $file = fopen($dir.'/'.$file_to_create,"w");
        fwrite($file, $file_content);
        fclose($file);
    }
}

?>
```

Now everything works fine and my folders are created with the index file in them and the content to write for each. But my problem is this, anytime I try to open the index file on my browser I always get this error for all the folders

> Forbidden: You do not have permission to access /forums/tags/tag_name on this server

Please anyone have an idea why I am getting this error? I am using a WAMP local server on my PC

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with your codes, the issue lies with the permission of the file or folder, change your file and folder permission

chmod -R 755 folder/ to change the permission of the folder as well as files inside the folder.

Run the chmod mode function in terminal but do remember to change directory to the correct folder.

From what I have research previously, folder permission is normally 755 while file permission is 644, but leaving it as 755 will works fine.

I just realised you are using wamp, which is for window,

- you can right click on the php files
- go under properties and go to security tab.
- click edit and give read,write and execute for user and read, execute for group and others.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on the file itself. On Windows, right-click the file, go to properties then on the security tab you are able to edit the permissions. When I'm not bothered about security I'll allow: "Modify", "Read & execute", "Read" and "Write". For SYSTEM allow "Full control" as well.

I speak from experience using a Linux server, and when I got a 403 I found this was the case.